# Laravel 5.1, export model to csv works but doesn't download

Tags: php, laravel, csv

This is the route for my controller and method:

`Route::post('exportarDireccionTodos','MyController@exportarDireccionTodos');`

I'm calling that route from a click button with javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    url: baseUrl+'exportarDireccionTodos',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {'id': optionsChecked},
    success: function(response) {
        //etc
```

`MyController` have this code:

```
$delimiter=";";
$array = MyModel::findMany($todos)->toArray();
$filename = "direcciones.csv";
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: UTF-8");
header('Content-Type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'";');

$f = fopen('php://output', 'wb');

foreach ($array as $line) {
    fputcsv($f, $line, $delimiter);
}
fclose($f)

return response()->json([
    'status' => 'success',
    'mensaje' => 'Direcciones exportadas a CSV'
]);
```

I'm sending some `id` to my model then I'm creating a csv file, but I can't download it, I just see it pretty well made in the developer tools XHR, like this:

[image]

I've tried with:

```
header('Content-Type: application/force-download');

header('Content-Type: text/csv');
```

And with:

```
return Response::download($f, $filename, $headers);  <-- here I got an error, Laravel 5.1 doesnt reconigze Response
```

same with:

```
return response()->download($f, $filename);
```

Always happens the same, the csv is made but can't download. I've tried 2 other ways to create the csv, but it always is well generated but can't be downloaded

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the headers in your last call

```
return response()->download($f, $filename, $headers);
```

I'm using these headers on my laravel app to download a file

```
$headers = [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/csv',
        "Content-Description" => "File Transfer",
        "Cache-Control" => "public",
        'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"',
];
```

You may have better luck storing the file temporarily and generating a URL to download from

```
$fs = Storage::disk('local')->temporaryUrl($path, now()->addMinutes(5));
```

Comment: but the 3rd parameter is optional in download() and I already have set the `headers()`in my code. Anyhow, I've just tested with headers, I always get the same: https://i.imgur.com/WJ0mf4W.png

Comment: Do you have the `php_fileinfo` extension enabled in php.ini?

Comment: Or possibly an empty string/space in a global include file (such as config)?

Comment: Hmm, emtoy string/space, don't think so, I'm using Laragon without anyproblems in other projects. And yes. I have `extension=php_fileinfo.dll`

Comment: What happens if you change it from a POST to a GET request and visit the URL in your browser? Same output?

Comment: I was trying that too, let me check once again. Yes, same behaviour: https://i.imgur.com/ku7hxah.png

Comment: Ahh no! there I can download, opening the XHR in new tab, I don't get it

Comment: So you can download via GET, but opening the XHR request in a new table (still GET), it doesn't download? Can you share both URLs here?

Comment: I don't know what is happening. When I right-click to open in new tab the XHR url, it works, and the download starts, but I can't make to do it directly from my ajax. The cvs is always there...

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem is my logic. I can't download a file with an ajax call.
I tried with Laravel-Excel but I had the same problem of coruse.

This thread fix my problem:

https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/issues/848

```
$response = array(
        'name' => "das",
        'file' => "data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;base64,".base64_encode($archivo) //mime type of used format
    );
```

and in the ajax:

```
var a = document.createElement("a");
a.href = response.file;
a.download = response.name;
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
a.remove();
```